# Phone not listed when using 'adb devices' command on mac

Tags: boot-loop, ota-update, macos, google-pixel, side-loading

My Google Pixel 2 is stuck in a boot loop and after searching for ways to fix this online I found  that applying a Rescue OTA to the device has solved a few people's issues.

Initially I downloaded the SDK Platform Tools from the android developer site and in my terminal, I cd'd into the platform-tools folder and used to command './fastboot devices' which showed my phones serial number, however my device wasn't listed when I used './adb devices' (typing the commands without the './' resulted in a "command not found" message). I then downloaded the SDK tools using homebrew instead and both 'fastboot devices' and 'adb devices' showed no devices.

I have no idea how to fix this. Google customer supports only suggestion was that I factory reset my phone but I haven't backed up my photos and was hoping to do that after I've exhausted all my other options.

Comment: It would be best if you would have access to a second working Android phone so you could test adb and fastboot and check if the problem is on MacOS or Android/USB side. Also check multiple USB ports and cables. Some cables may be charge-only cables.

Comment: @Robert thanks! I'll try that later today.

Comment: for the general misconception: when `fastboot devices` shows the device, `adb devices` **cannot,** and vice versa – that's by design. ADB cannot show devices in fastboot/bootloader mode – and fastboot can do *only* that. You might wish to check out our corresponding tag wikis: [adb](/tags/adb/info) and [fastboot](/tags/fastboot/info).